# Win32 - passing data to CreateThread in a "safe" way

Tags: winapi, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a code base which creates threads ad-hoc in a few places with the following pattern:

1. Use `operator new` to create a struct that will contain "the stuff" the thread wants to work with.
2. Call win32 `CreateThread()` API.
3. In the thread proc cast the LPVOID to the object `new`'ed in step 1.
4. Use the object and then manually `delete` it.

This works but has a couple of issues:

1. Static code analyzers think that the objected in step 1 can be leaked, I guess this is in fact true for cases where `CreateThread` fails.
2. I'd like  a way to make this more RAII/automatic.
3. The manual casting can be error prone.

I figured that `std::shared_ptr` might be the solution, e.g in step 1 replace `new` with `std::make_shared`. But this seems to have other problems:

1. I don't think that same instance of `std::shared_ptr` can be used in the other thread?
2. What if the function which calls `CreateThread` exits before the thread proc starts, then it is using a dangling pointer?

Can anyone suggest a more elegant and safe way of doing this? The only other option I can think of is to have a class that wraps `CreateThread` and has `std::shared_ptr` as a member and then calls a lamba as the thread proc?

Comment: `I'd like a way to make this more RAII/automatic.` One word: `std::thread` (or is it two words?)

Comment: `a class that wraps CreateThread and has std::shared_ptr as a member and then calls a lamba as the thread proc` In fact, you more or less described `std::thread`

Comment: so std::thread is the way to go? Just pass it a function and a shared_ptr?

Comment: One way to do it, yes.

Comment: @paulm: Yes. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread for an example.

Comment: seems std::thread isn't all that RAII after all, you must wrap it in a RAII object to auto detatch or join.